# Datacap Email count and connect to a specific folder

Tags: ibm-datacap

I have two requirements in Datacap 9.0.1

1. I want to find how many emails that were sent to the done folder and
   how many were sent to problem folder. This way, I can alert the
   users that say, out of 10 emails in the inbox, 7 of them processed
   successfully and 3 moved to the problematic folder. I know
   EmailCount variable gives me the count of emails that datacap was
   able to read successfully/moved them to the done folder but what I
   want is the initial count of emails so that I can find a difference.
2. Is it possible within datacap to scan a folder other than Inbox? For
   Ex, if I want to scan 'Sent Items' folder how would I do that? I
   looked into the email connection actions, but I don't see anything
   which can help me to connect to the folder that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the answer that I got from another datacap forum. Posting it here so that it helps others

***Not sure about number 1. I believe that would require modifications to the mail actions.
For #2, no, there is no way to specify something other than inbox.
Both of these would likely require some sort of enhancement.***

Here the enhancement means creating datacap custom actions. I haven't tried creating one and in case if I happen to create, will post the details of it.